# How to address specific elements in a dictionary using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, api, dictionary

I'm working with an API and essentially what I'm looking to achieve is extract a list of surveys and save them to a CSV file. The output I receive when extracting the list of surveys is in JSON format so my thinking is to convert this into a Pandas data frame and then it should be straightforward to export it to CSV. When I convert the JSON output, it converts it to a dictionary with multiple elements but I only need to pull out one element which is the surveys.

So the dictionary holds 2 dictionary elements, 1 called 'meta' and one called 'result'. The 'result' dictionary holds a list called 'elements' (which is where the survey information I need is, all of which are stored in dictionaries) and 'nextPage' which is a NoneType element. How do I just pull out the survey information in the 'elements' list?

My code currently looks like this:

```
apiToken = "n000000000"
dataCenter = "https://group.qualtrics.com"

baseUrl = "https://group.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys"
headers = {
    "x-api-token": apiToken,
    }

response = requests.get(baseUrl, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

surveys = response.text
surveys2 = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.read_json (surveys2.result.elements)
df.to_csv('survey_list.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access python dictionary fields you use index operator like this:

```py
elements = surveys2['result']['elements']
```

Alternatively when you are not sure whether dictory has some field you can use `get` operator with some default value:

```py
elements = surveys2['result'].get('elements', [])
```